# Sending data to a window popup from the parent window using window.open when they are from a different domain

Tags: javascript, window.open

i am trying to send some data from the parent window to the popup window using this approach:

```
const mywindow = window.open(RE_SID_URL,"toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=0,resizable=1,left=400,width=500");
mywindow.myName = "myname".
```

but in the popup window , it does not get set in the window object , Accessing window.opener in the popup is showing this error:
Exception: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame. at invokeGetter (:1:142).
what am i doing wrong here ,any help is appreciated. I am accessing a different host but the same domain in the popup.

Comment: Notice the missing `name` argument, that should be the second argument for `open`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have domain problems and you want to communicate, send messages.

```
/* the "Server" */

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {

  // ... security check
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ... process message
}

...

/* the "Client" */

targetWindow = window.opener;
// or targetWindow = HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow;
// or targetWindow = window.open(RE_SID_URL, ...)

targetWindow.postMessage("some message", "*");
// or targetWindow.postMessage( {"data":2, "msg":"something"} , "*");
```